# Who/what is listening at /signin-microsoft?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I am using external logins for my ASP.NET MVC project.

In the latest version of the Visual Studio MVC project template, the redirect url passed to the external provider is `/signin-microsoft`, `/signin-google`, etc. After the external provider successfully authenticates the user, it redirects the browser to this url. However, inside the MVC app, I can't find a method at this url.

Who or what is listening at `/signin-xxxx`?

I need to troubleshoot as it works for all providers but not for Microsoft. `/signin-microsoft` will redirect the user to `/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2FHome&error=access_denied`.